# GUID/ProgId/CLSID confusion

Tags: com, guid, uuid

Trying to track down a COM problem, I'm debugging my code and seeming to see the same GUID represented different ways...

I have a line in our code:
`class __declspec(uuid("{D4F83347-E58E-11d1-9D47-006008098294}"))`

And various registry stuff in between, then a call to:

```
CLSID clsid;
::CLSIDFromProgID("myProgId",&clsid);
```

In the debugger, clsid is displayed as `{000AFC9A-3347-D4F8-8EE5-D1119D470060}`. To me this is too similar not to be right, but it's not something I can check automatically... we've got the D4F8 and 3347, 9D47, but E58E becomes 8EE5 etc.

Is there a way I can understand why this is happening, and a way I can get them to look the same for comparison?

**EDIT**
To clear up some side-tracking, I've checked and the CLSID in the Windows registry and our registration scripts is presented as `{D4F83347-E58E-11d1-9D47-006008098294}` too - so the issue over my `uuid(...)` is not relevant I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, I discovered that the issue was simply how the visual C++ debugger was displaying the value, nothing more. e.g the registry value is `{D4F83347-E58E-11d1-9D47-006008098294}`, calling `::StringToCLSID()` on the result of `CLSIDFromProgID()` gives `{D4F83347-E58E-11d1-9D47-006008098294}` - but in the debugger MSVC++ *displays* the variable as `{000AFC9A-3347-D4F8-8EE5-D1119D470060}`.

*Why* it does that, is another question!

Answer (score 1):

Using CLSIDFromProgID() when you already have the guid doesn't make much sense.  The function looks in the registry to map the "ProgId" string to the CLSID {guid}.  Which of course makes it important that the progid is registered properly.  Sure sounds like it is not.  When your class is already decorated with `__declspec(uuid)` then simply use the [__uuidof() operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaah6a61%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to retrieve the guid.

The similarity in the byte values suggests that your registration code is broken.

Comment: This is how we present it in our reg-scripts too. For instance I checked the registry and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myProgId\CLSID = {D4F83347-E58E-11d1-9D47-006008098294}` i.e. the same format I post from my code. So then it seems to be registered right, but then returned in the other format. FYI we use progIds as strings to load stuff dynamically, but it's a big old client-server system with origins lost in history :)

Comment: Well, just take a look with Regedit.exe and check the actual value written there.  If it doesn't match then either forgot to re-register the DLL or you'll have to debug your registration code.

Comment: As per my previous comment, that _IS_ from regedit. That is the format we use _everyehere_, and yet MSVC++ debugger shows the result of `CLSIDFromProgID()` in this other format. Actually - is this perhaps simply a debugger issue how it presents GUIDS?

Comment: I don't know, never heard of this going wrong.  Anything is possible if you monkeyed with autoexp.dat.  The debugger looks in the registry to try to map the CLSID to a name, using the default value of the `CLSID\{guid}` key.  I've got nothing to look at to help you diagnose this.

Comment: From some testing, it seems that it _is_ simply the way MSVC++ displays the GUID in the debugger which caused the problem - if I call `::StringToCLSID()` on the value it then takes the expected format. So something of a curveball!

Answer (score 1):

"__declspec(uuid" is only an association of the identifier to your class, nothing else. Using `CLSIDFromProgID` API you are resolving ProgID to CLSID using registration infromation in system registry. That is, the two don't have to match. They typically do match though if you do everything neatly and your COM class is registered with the same identifier as the one being attached in source code to the C++ class.